# Having Problems storing values in hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, postfix-notation

Okay I am kind of new to java. I am creating a Postfix Calculator and I am trying to create a memory for it using a hashmap. The user is supposed to be able to assign his/her own variable for example:

```
> a = 3 5 + 1 -
7
> bee = a 3 *
21
> a bee +
28
> bee 3 %
0
> a = 4
4
> 57
57
> 2 c +
c not found
> mem
a: 4
bee: 21
> exit
```

The user uses "var =" to assign a variable and can later use it to recall a prior answer. 
I cannot get my compute method to ignore the "a =" so it returns an error and the when I run the program and try to use a variable I get the errors

```
>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
 Error"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Program6.main(Program6.java:38)
```

is there a good way to somehow get my compute method to ignore the variable input, and whats the best way to implement the hashmap? I seem to have gotten stuck. Here's my code so far

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Program6
{
    private static HashMap<String,Integer> memory = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Servando Hernandez");
        System.out.println("RPN command line calculator");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(">");
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.print("> ");
            String a = scan.nextLine(); 
            String b = "quit";
            String c = "mem";
            String d = "clear";
            if(a.equals(b))
            { 
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(compute(a));
            }
            System.out.print(">");

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(!a.isEmpty())
            {
                StringTokenizer var = new StringTokenizer(a);
                while(var.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    list.add(var.nextToken());
                }
            }
            int pos = Integer.parseInt(compute(a));



            memory.put(list.get(l.size()-1),pos);

        }   


    }



    public static String compute(String input)
    {
        List<String> processedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!input.isEmpty()) 
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                processedList.add(st.nextToken());
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            return "Error";
        }
        Stack<String> tempList = new Stack<String>();

        Iterator<String> iter = processedList.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext())
            {
                String temp = iter.next();
                if (temp.matches("[0-9]*"))
                    {

                    tempList.push(temp);
                    }
                    else if (temp.matches("[*-/+]")) 
                    {

                        if (temp.equals("*")) 
                        {
                            int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int result = ls * rs;
                            tempList.push("" + result);
                        } 
                        else if (temp.equals("-")) 
                        {
                            int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int result = ls - rs;
                            tempList.push("" + result);
                        } 
                        else if (temp.equals("/")) 
                        {
                            int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int result = ls / rs;
                            tempList.push("" + result);
                        } 
                        else if (temp.equals("+")) 
                        {
                            int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int result = ls + rs;
                            tempList.push("" + result);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "Error";
                    }
            }

        return tempList.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had debug your code, find the **matches** method make something wrong.

When you input something like `1+1`, `matches("[0-9]*")` and `matches("[*-/+]")` are all return **false**, so the code entry the else branch and `return "Error";`

And, you put a string "Error" into `Integer.parseInt()`, so it throw the Exception.

For give my poor English.

Comment: Oh sorry I assumed everyone knew what a PostFix calculator was. The user must input each argument with a space and the operator goes after the you input the integers.

Comment: I input `1 + 1`, and in the compute method code                                                      `else if (temp.equals("+")) 
                        {  // you pop first and your tempList would be null, so when you pop again, them throw Exception
                            int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                            int result = ls + rs;
                            tempList.push("" + result);
                        }`

Comment: How to create a new line in comment, too hard to show code